# How to display image from database in bootstrap thumbnail 3 column view?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my code and I am using bootstrap 3.x.x:

```
<div class="row ">
     <div class="col-xs-6">
              <h3>Gallery</h3>
          <?php
          $query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_gallery")or die(mysql_error());
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
           $id=$row['Photo_ID'];
           ?>
           <a class="thumbnail" href="adminln/<?php echo $row['Photo']; ?>" > <img class="img-inline" src="adminln/<?php echo $row['Photo']; ?>" alt="http://placehold.it/700x400"/>
           </a>
           <?php } ?>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using Bootstrap with a 3 column thumbnail image gallery. Each image is sized to 150x150. In this example, you should have the following three database columns: image, title, and description (and probably a primary key ID column as well). It is highly recommended to use the mysqli extension and stay away from mysql; or even better, use PDO to protect from deprecated code as well as SQL injections and more.

- 'Image' contains the actual name of the .jpg file such as "chickens.jpg"
- 'Title' contains the name of the image for the IMG ALT attribute
- 'Description' contains a description of the image

*This example code is untested*

```
<?php
// create new array
$thumbnails = array();
$query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_gallery")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    // add new record to array
    $thumbnails[] = $row;

    // check to see if array has 3 records in it
    if (count($thumbnails) === 3)
    {
        echo <<<EOT
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="adminln/$thumbnails[0]['image']" class="thumbnail">
                        <p>$thumbnails[0]['description']</p> 
                        <img src="adminln/$thumbnails[0]['image']" alt="$thumbnails[0]['title']" width="150" height="150">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="adminln/$thumbnails[1]['image']" class="thumbnail">
                        <p>$thumbnails[1]['description']</p>
                        <img src="adminln/$thumbnails[1]['image']" alt="$thumbnails[1]['title']" width="150" height="150">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="adminln/$thumbnails[2]['image']" class="thumbnail">
                        <p>$thumbnails[2]['description']</p> 
                        <img src="adminln/$thumbnails[2]['image']" alt="$thumbnails[2]['title']" width="150" height="150">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        EOT;

        // empty the array
        $thumbnails = array();
    }
}
?>
```